# How to change UI based on server variable state in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a boolean variable in my server side code based on which I want to decide whether to render some HTML text or not when the usre first sends the request.

The variable is not a client property ( for which I can use deferred binding). I also want to avoid RPC communication.

Is there some simple way by which I can inject conditionally inject HTML text.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use JSP for your host page. Otherwise, you can map your domain to a servlet and add a logic inside this servlet to decide which file to return.